# What are the NuGet package abbreviations for Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android?

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.ios, nuget

I'm in the process of retargeting my NuGet package for Xamarin.iOS (both classic + unified APIs) and Xamarin.Android. My question is, what would be the proper directory name to put the assembly under before publishing it? For example, right now I have:

```
portable-net45+win+wpa81
```

because my PCL targets .NET Framework 4.5, Windows 8 and Windows Phone 8.1. What do I add to this to make sure that my package can be installed on Xamarin platforms?

I found out the proper abbreviations after substantial digging through the [NuGet documentation](http://docs.nuget.org/Create/Enforced-Package-Conventions), but it doesn't mention Xamarin.

Answer (score 1):

Well, looks like I answered my own question before I got to post it. The answer is

```
portable-net45+win+wpa81+MonoAndroid10+xamarinios10+MonoTouch10
```

For future reference: I remembered I **didn't** find the proper abbreviations out through the docs, but through my own ingenuity:

1. Make a new PCL that targets said platforms
2. `nuget spec Foo.csproj`
3. Retouch as needed
4. `nuget pack Foo.csproj`
5. Rename `Foo.nupkg` to `Foo.zip`
6. Open zip file (or extract && open)
7. Proper name for directory is in lib folder (replace %2B with + as needed)

Hope that helps!

Comment: You do not need to add the Mono and Xamarin target frameworks to your Portable Class Library profile. They are treated as optional by NuGet. You can install a PCL into a Xamarin.Android or iOS project without having these frameworks defined on the PCL in the NuGet package. Json.NET for example does not specify any Xamarin frameworks.